# spliting one column to three columns in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
name       test       count 
----------------------------   
sam        test1        10
sam        test2         2
sam        passcount     5
riz        test4         3
riz        test5         4
riz        passxount     6
```

I want to display the result

```
name             test              pass count            fail count                  total count 
-------------------------------------------------------------------   
sam              test1                 7                    10                               17
sam              test2                15                     2                               17 
riz              test 4               10                     3
riz              test 5                9                     4                                  13
```

Comment: And what is the *logic* behind this? How is the first table converted into the result?? Given `name = 'sam'` and `test = 'test1'` - how do you find out the "pass count" or the "fail count"? You need to provide a lot more information - not just a bunch of data rows!!

Comment: What's the _magic_ involved to come up with the values for the new column?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it took a little bit of time to realize the column headers were slightly missleading

```
/**
    pass = total for name minus that for current test
    fail = total count for that test in src table
    total = total count for that name
*/

select 
    t1.name,
    t1.test,
    t2.total-t1.count as pass_count,
    t1.count as fail_count,
    t2.total as total_count
from Kamrams_table as t1
inner join 
    (
    select 
        k1.name,
        sum(k1.count) as total
    from Kamrams_table as k1
    group by k1.name
    ) as t2
on t1.name = t2.name
;
```

Notes: 
I believe the extra space between test4 and test 5 in output table was a typo?
There are other constructs that would be useful: CTE and windowing functions.